# Why are askubuntu.com and meta.askubuntu.com considered as same site?

Tags: support, design, meta

Why are askubuntu.com and meta.askubuntu.com considered as same Stack Exchange site (Same Reputation points on both site), while stackoverflow.com and meta.stackoverflow.com are considered as different sites (Different Reputation points on both sites)

Comment: It's not is it? On my askubuntu account I have different reputation to my meta account.

Comment: @handuel - Are you sure you have different reputation points? My reputation score reflects across askubuntu.com and meta.askubuntu.com. Only badges earned are different.

Comment: Ah, I think I just needed to clear my cache, I was a few points down on meta, but I did a uncached reload and it's the same.

Comment: Note for future readers: [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) is now the meta site for the entire network, while [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) is the meta site for just Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because MSO is special. It was the first meta site and handles all the suggestions and bugs for the entire SE network, not just SO.

I think if they had the choice to start over, they'd probably make it rep-free like the rest of SE's metas but there you go. There's no going back without annoying a load of people.